# ¿Cómo se instalan las dependencias en un proyecto en Angular?

Tags: nodejs, angular, npm, packages

Se que en el package.json esta indicado todo lo que hay que instalar.
También se que hay un comando en npm que hay que ejecutar cuando acabas de bajarte un proyecto de git, ya que las librerías no se guardan en git, solo las referencias en el package.json.
La cosa es que no encuentro cual era ese comando....

Espero encontrar la respuesta pronto y tal vez contestarme a mi mismo, pero veo útil que esta pregunta exita aqui.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Te colocas desde la consola a nivel de la carpeta raíz de tu proyecto, algo así:

```
C:\Users\tuuser\Desktop\proyecto>
```

Una vez dentro de dicha carpeta vas a ejecutar el comando:

```
C:\Users\tuuser\Desktop\proyecto> npm install
```

Lo anterior iniciará el proceso de descarga de los paquetes que existen declarados dentro de tu archivo `package.json`.

Si tienes mas dudas al respecto del comando, ejecuta `npm install -h` y te mostrará información extra al respecto al momento de usarlo

```
C:\Users\tuuser\Desktop\proyecto>npm install -h

npm install (with no args, in package dir)
npm install [<@scope>/]<pkg>
npm install [<@scope>/]<pkg>@<tag>
npm install [<@scope>/]<pkg>@<version>
npm install [<@scope>/]<pkg>@<version range>
npm install <folder>
npm install <tarball file>
npm install <tarball url>
npm install <git:// url>
npm install <github username>/<github project>

aliases: i, isntall, add
common options: [--save-prod|--save-dev|--save-optional] [--save-exact] [--no-save]

C:\Users\tuuser\Desktop\proyecto>
```

Answer (score 4):

Los proyectos hechos con angular suelen usar el [Angular CLI (Command Line Interpreter)](https://cli.angular.io/), pero siguen dependiendo de `npm`, así que los pasos para probarlo serían:

```
npm install
```

Este comando instalará las dependencias (en `./node_modules`). Una vez tengas las dependencias bajadas, podrás ejecutar

```
ng serve
```

Que ejecutará un servidor web que escucha en el puerto 4200, con lo que podrás probar la aplicación tal cual está (`http://localhost:4200`)

Comment: También  `npm start `  o `ng serve -o`  si quieres que se ejecute el navegador ¿Correcto?